# Multi-line header is not working.

Tags: java, swing, jtable, multiline, jtableheader

I drag jtabel from palette and  i try to customize the code for multi-line header but in table it's not showed.sorry for my ugly English. thanks in advance

```
jTable1=new javax.swing.JTable(); 

jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {

        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
));

jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jTable1);

jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("poa\nsfh");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default renderers in Swing use a JLabel to render the text. A JLabel doesn't not recognize the "\n" String.

A JLabel can display HTML, so you can try using HTML for the heading. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) for more information.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that sorry i am new to this

Comment: @Sanchai_28, `i am new to this` then its time to read the Swing tutorial. See my editfor a link to the tutorial and don't forget to look at the table of contents for other basic Swing information.

Comment: @Sanchai_28, works fine for me. Did you use "<br>" as the HTML tag for a new line? Edit your question and post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem along with the HTML code that you tried.

Comment: Oh my Bad.i forget to add <br>@camickr thank you for your support